# Tower of Hanoi recursion solution explanation

Tags: recursion, towers-of-hanoi

I have struggled with Tower of Hanoi problem for 3 months. Here's the simplest code I can find:

```
void moveDisk(int n, char from, char to, char buffer)
{
    if(n == 1)
    {
        cout << "Move disk 1 from " << from << " to " << to << endl;
        return;
    }
    moveDisk(n-1, from, buffer, to);
    cout << "Move disk " << n << " from " << from << " to " << to << endl;
    moveDisk(n-1, buffer, to, from);
}

int main()
{
    moveDisk(3, 'A', 'C', 'B');
}
```

And it works perfectly well:

```
Move disk 1 from A to C
Move disk 2 from A to B
Move disk 1 from C to B
Move disk 3 from A to C
Move disk 1 from B to A
Move disk 2 from B to C
Move disk 1 from A to C
```

My biggest question is: Why it works?

I have done some research and they all say that: "Move the first n-1 disks to the 'buffer', then move the n disk to the 'to' stack and finally move the first n-1 disks to the 'to' stack. I understand the idea of it, but my question is: why writing the code that way works? Also: why do we need to print:

```
cout << "Move disk 1 from " << from << " to " << to << endl;
```

in the base case in order for it to work? If according to the idea above, why don't we just return when we hit the base case instead?

I tried to track the recursion by hand and the variable "from", "to", and "buffer" keep changing constantly - but somehow it works!

Please explain to me why?

Thank you!

Comment: This question belongs on the math stack exchange.

Comment: "Why we have to write .." -- if you don't, the algorithm still works. But how would you know what it is doing? Printing out the final result is not useful, as it would only print out that the disks are ordered again.